# Custom control with non-client area - doesn't calculate at first

Tags: delphi, winapi, custom-controls, nonclient-area

I'm writing a custom control which is simply a container with a non-client area. Within that non-client area, there's one small area which is a button, and the rest of it is transparent. The drawing isn't an exact rectangle.

So far, I have it half-way working. The problem is that it doesn't calculate the non-client area up front, unless I make a minor tweak, such as re-sizing it.

I've followed many resources describing how to accomplish this. My implementation of handling `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is more or less identical to "working" examples I've found. But when the control is first created, it does not calculate this at all. When I drop a breakpoint inside the message handler of mine (`WMNCCalcSize`), based on the examples I've found, I'm supposed to first check `Msg.CalcValidRects`, and only do my calculation if it's `True`. But when debugging run-time, it's `False`, thus the calculation isn't done.

In design-time, if I re-size the control, THEN it decides to calculate properly. It's still not perfect (this code is still in the works), but it doesn't seem to set the non-client area until after I tweak it. Further, in run-time, if I tweak the size in the code, it still doesn't calculate.

[image: Before and After Resize]

The image on the top is when the form is initially created/shown. The second one is after I re-size it a little bit. Notice the test button, which is aligned `alLeft`. So initially, it consumes the area which is supposed to be non-client.

If I comment out the check `if Msg.CalcValidRects then begin`, then it calculates properly. But I see every example doing this check, and I'm pretty sure it's needed.

What am I doing wrong and how to make it calculate the non-client area at all times?

```
unit FloatBar;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Forms,
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages;

type
  TFloatBar = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FCollapsed: Boolean;
    FBtnHeight: Integer;
    FBtnWidth: Integer;
    procedure RepaintBorder;
    procedure PaintBorder;
    procedure SetCollapsed(const Value: Boolean);
    function BtnRect: TRect;
    procedure SetBtnHeight(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetBtnWidth(const Value: Integer);
    function TransRect: TRect;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
    procedure WMNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Repaint; override;
    procedure Invalidate; override;
  published
    property BtnWidth: Integer read FBtnWidth write SetBtnWidth;
    property BtnHeight: Integer read FBtnHeight write SetBtnHeight;
    property Collapsed: Boolean read FCollapsed write SetCollapsed;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Float Bar', [TFloatBar]);
end;

{ TFloatBar }

constructor TFloatBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ControlStyle:= [csAcceptsControls,
    csCaptureMouse,
    csDesignInteractive,
    csClickEvents,
    csReplicatable,
    csNoStdEvents
    ];
  Width:= 400;
  Height:= 60;
  FBtnWidth:= 50;
  FBtnHeight:= 20;
  FCollapsed:= False;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params.WindowClass do
    Style := Style and not (CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW);
end;

destructor TFloatBar.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.Invalidate;
begin
  inherited;
  RepaintBorder;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.Repaint;
begin
  inherited Repaint;
  RepaintBorder;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.RepaintBorder;
begin
  if Visible and HandleAllocated then
    Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TFloatBar.SetBtnHeight(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FBtnHeight := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.SetBtnWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FBtnWidth := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.SetCollapsed(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FCollapsed := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
begin
  inherited;
  PaintBorder;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.WMNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize);
var
  lpncsp: PNCCalcSizeParams;
begin
  if Msg.CalcValidRects then begin            //<------ HERE --------
    lpncsp := Msg.CalcSize_Params;
    if lpncsp = nil then Exit;
    lpncsp.rgrc[0].Bottom:= lpncsp.rgrc[0].Bottom-FBtnHeight;
    Msg.Result := 0;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

function TFloatBar.BtnRect: TRect;
begin
  //Return a rect where the non-client collapse button is to be...
  Result:= Rect(ClientWidth-FBtnWidth, ClientHeight, ClientWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight);
end;

function TFloatBar.TransRect: TRect;
begin
  //Return a rect where the non-client transparent area is to be...
  Result:= Rect(0, ClientHeight, ClientWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight);
end;

procedure TFloatBar.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  P: TPoint;
  C: TCursor;
begin
  C:= crDefault; //TODO: Find a way to change cursor elsewhere...
  P:= Point(Message.XPos, Message.YPos);
  if PtInRect(BtnRect, P) then begin
    Message.Result:= HTCLIENT;
    C:= crHandPoint;
  end else
  if PtInRect(TransRect, P) then
    Message.Result:= HTTRANSPARENT
  else
    inherited;
  Screen.Cursor:= C;
end;

procedure TFloatBar.Paint;
begin
  inherited;

  //Paint Background
  Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Style:= psClear;
  Canvas.Brush.Color:= Color;
  Canvas.FillRect(Canvas.ClipRect);

  Canvas.Pen.Style:= psSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Width:= 3;
  Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsClear;
  Canvas.Pen.Color:= clBlue;

  Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, 0); //Top
  Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight); //Right
  Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-FBtnWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight); //Bottom of Button
  Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-FBtnWidth, ClientHeight); //Left of Button
  Canvas.LineTo(0, ClientHeight); //Bottom
  Canvas.LineTo(0, 0);

end;

procedure TFloatBar.PaintBorder;
begin
  Canvas.Handle:= GetWindowDC(Handle);
  try

    //TODO: Paint "transparent" area by painting parent...


    //Paint NC button background
    Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
    Canvas.Pen.Style:= psClear;
    Canvas.Brush.Color:= Color;
    Canvas.Rectangle(ClientWidth-FBtnWidth, ClientHeight, ClientWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight);

    //Paint NC button border
    Canvas.Pen.Style:= psSolid;
    Canvas.Pen.Width:= 3;
    Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsClear;
    Canvas.Pen.Color:= clBlue;
    Canvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
    Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight);
    Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-FBtnWidth, ClientHeight+FBtnHeight);
    Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-FBtnWidth, ClientHeight);

    //Paint NC Button Chevron      //TODO: Calculate chevron size/position
    if FCollapsed then begin
      Canvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth-30, ClientHeight+7);
      Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-25, ClientHeight+13);
      Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-20, ClientHeight+7);
    end else begin
      Canvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth-30, ClientHeight+13);
      Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-25, ClientHeight+7);
      Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth-20, ClientHeight+13);
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, Canvas.Handle);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: when you will release source code of this component in your [Github repository](https://github.com/djjd47130/FloatBar)?

Comment: @user9672569 As soon as I think it's ready to be released. I haven't been working on it lately.

Comment: ok. I will wait ;-)

Comment: I have searched by a component like this many time, when you will release? i see that still not is complete.

Comment: @Davison I haven't been actively working on this in a long time. I got stuck on the topic of smoothly keeping it positioned in the center automatically, which is critical for such a control. I myself have no need for it, and nobody's paying me for it, so I have no motivation to continue writing it.

Comment: could post all code **until where you stopped** on your Github repository to reference please.

Comment: @Davison It's really not much more than the code above, and it's severely broken. It would take me a day or two to even get it in any workable condition, time which I barely have, especially here on the holidays. I don't even have a local repo copy for my code yet - just that empty repo.

Comment: @Davison Okay I posted my [code](https://github.com/djjd47130/FloatBar) but like I said, it's severely broken at the moment and far from workable.

Comment: OK thank you very much, if someday you complete this project, also say me here please :-).

Comment: @Davison It would be nice to know some desired use-cases so I know what types of features to implement. For example, the non-client tab may or may not have an extra "full screen" button just like TeamViewer, or perhaps multiple NC buttons? Built-in menus, or just a simple container for custom menus?

Comment: in your project you says: `- "mimicing that of TeamViewer"`, then i think that this project must be the more near (of Team View) that you is able to make. I suggest that **inside** your FloatBar have only tab's where the programmer can insert any other component that he need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ... I'm supposed to first check `Msg.CalcValidRects`, and only do my
>   calculation if it's `True`.

You've got that wrong. The message has a somewhat complicated mechanism and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx) might be slightly confusing trying to explain two distinct mode the message operates (`wParam` true or false). The part that relates to your case is the second paragraph of `lParam`:

> If wParam is **FALSE**, lParam points to a **RECT** structure. On entry, the
>   structure contains the proposed window rectangle for the window. On
>   exit, the structure should contain the screen coordinates of the
>   corresponding window client area.

You'll find numerous usage examples of this simple form in the VCL where `wParam` is not checked at all, like in `TToolWindow.WMNCCalcSize`, `TCustomCategoryPanel.WMNCCalcSize` etc..

(Note that `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS.rgrc` is not even a rectangle array when `wParam` is false, but since you're operating on the supposed *first* rectangle, you're fine.)